# Xamarin Android Set switch position

Tags: android, xamarin

Does anyone know how to set a switch position by code? For example, I want to set all my switches to off when i press a button... cant figure it out.

Comment: Use the `checked` property of the toggle (switches in android are called toggles) button. For example `view.FindViewById<ToggleButton>(Resource.Id.toggleButton).Checked = false`.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the Switch by the id property in the axml (android:id="@+id/switch1" for example) and then set the **Checked** property:

```
Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);

Switch switchControl = FindViewById<Switch>(Resource.Id.switch1);

button.Click += delegate {
    switchControl.Checked = true; // or false
};
```